# Install the HPE System Management Homepage on Windows Server 2016 (HPE DL 380 G10)

Tags: hp-proliant, windows-server-2016, hpe

I have an new HPE ProLiant DL380 G10 server with Windows Server 2016 on it.

As i was used to i:

- downloaded the HPE SPP (Service Pack for ProLiant) in Version 2018.03
- and first updated the Firmware,
- than build a RAID,
- installed the OS (win16).

After that i was used to copy the SPP ISO to the Windows Server and start the **SUM (Smart Update Manager)** to install additional HPE Software and drivers.

Everything worked fine until i noticed **that i can not find the HPE System management Homepage in HP SUM.**

I tried to find it on the HPE Homepage but could't find anything that goes with DL380 in Generation 10 and Windows 2016.

- Has it been discontinued?
- Or is it not available for my configuration (Gen10 and Win16)?
- Has someone had an similar problem or an hint for me what has
  changed?

As i said i installed the SMH always over the SPP and now it seems not to work anymore this way...

#

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**

What i found out:
System Management Homepage in newest version (7.6.3.) is included in SPP 2018.03. It is the package "cp034022.exe". If i try to install it manually i get the failure:

***Unsupported G10(ProLiant DL380 Gen10) server model***

[image]

So any idea what to do now? So there is really no version of HPE SMH for G10 Servers?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess they were serious when the published this:

https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_b36fb879335a41d78ee5e99f7f#tab4

Important:

SMH 7.6.0 & later versions, will support only Gen 8 and Gen 9 servers. Any future patch releases could be available, only on SMH web page.

https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=c05330584
November 2016 release for Linux and Windows
HPE SMH 7.6 for Linux and Windows is the last release for this product and after this release the product will move into maintenance phase.